# Why Systemd path unit does not restart service

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, systemd, ubuntu-18.04

I use Ubuntu 18.04. I created service and path unit for my Sneakers workers process.

sneakers.service:

```
[Unit]
Description=sneakers
After=syslog.target network.target
[Service]
Type=simple
WorkingDirectory=/home/deploy/rails_app/current
ExecStart=/home/deploy/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle exec rails sneakers:run
User=deploy
Group=deploy
UMask=0002
Environment=MALLOC_ARENA_MAX=2
Environment=RAILS_ENV=production
RestartSec=1
Restart=on-failure
StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog
SyslogIdentifier=sneakers
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And sneakers.path

```
[Path]
PathModified=/home/deploy/rails_app/current/tmp/restart.txt
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then I enabled them and started path unit:

```
sudo systemctl enable sneakers.{path,service}
sudo systemctl start sneakers.path
```

It starts ok, service script works fine. But it does not restarts when file restart.txt is changed (I tried touching it and modifying).

I tried step-by-step tutorial https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/introduction-path-units - and it works fine on my system. The difference is that this tutorial uses some short running (one time) script that exists after execution. While my service uses long running foreground task in ExecStart.

How can I make my service work and restart with file touching?

Comment: Are you sure your Rails app is running? It's not clear what you're trying to do at all here. The `tmp/restart.txt` file is read by Rails to restart the app. Nothing external is needed. You don't need a systemd path unit at all, and it won't work anyway, as path units only start services, not restart them.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I fixed my description. This service is for running sneakers workers process (ActiveJob). And I try to make it restart with simultaneously with my Rails app, by touching restart.txt

Answer (score 3):

`systemd.path` units do not ***re***start services, but only *start* them. Here is a method where you define new "watcher" service unit and path unit that will start *and* restart **your** service(s): https://superuser.com/questions/1171751/restart-systemd-service-automatically-whenever-a-directory-changes-any-file-ins

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `PathChanged` ?

`PathChanged=` may be used to watch a file or directory and activate the configured unit whenever it changes. It is not activated on every write to the watched file but it is activated if the file which was open for writing gets closed.

`PathModified=` is similar, but additionally it is activated also on simple writes to the watched file.

your reference link opened a bug for path unit is not catching all events https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1722627

Comment: I tried both PathChanged and PathModified - no result.